# How to get coffeescript to wait for images to load

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript

So, I'm fairly new to coffeescript. I see $ -> is equivalent to $(function(){ }); for waiting for the DOM to load, but does anyone know the coffeescript equivalent of $(window).load(function() { }); for waiting until images are loaded? I've been searching on Google for half an hour and have found nothing....

Comment: have you tried the coffee to js converter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well moments after posting this I found http://js2coffee.org/. Pretty sweet tool! Oh and here's the solution, javascript:

```
$(window).load(function() {
    alert('foo');    
});
```

and equivalent coffeescript:

```
$(window).load ->
  alert "foo"
```

For some reason that translator added a third "return" line to the coffeescript even though I don't believe it's necessary.